# Error when update Manjaro system with pacman command - npm conflict files error message

Tags: npm, archlinux, manjaro

When I try to update the system "**Manjaro**" with the command:

> $ sudo pacman -Syyu

The same gives an error when trying to update the package "npm". Claiming file conflicts.

I tried to add it with the command:

> $ sudo pacman -Qo /usr/lib/node_modules

The same returned me the following ...

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/ is owned by node-gyp 6.1.0-1
/usr/lib/node_modules/ is owned by semver 7.1.1-1
/usr/lib/node_modules/ is owned by yarn 1.21.1-1
```

However when trying to rerun "**sudo pacman -Syyu**" the error persists.

Already tried as I suggest in some posts, solve with the following command:

> $ sudo pacman -Svyy npm --overwrite /usr/lib/node_modules

Even so the error persists as we can see in the log below:

> $ sudo pacman -Svyy npm --overwrite /usr/lib/node_modules/npm

```
Root      : /
Conf File : /etc/pacman.conf
DB Path   : /var/lib/pacman/
Cache Dirs: /var/cache/pacman/pkg/  
Hook Dirs : /usr/share/libalpm/hooks/  /etc/pacman.d/hooks/  
Lock File : /var/lib/pacman/db.lck
Log File  : /var/log/pacman.log
GPG Dir   : /etc/pacman.d/gnupg/
Targets   : npm
:: Synchronizing package databases...
 core                                                                                               167,9 KiB   749 KiB/s 00:00 [#############################################################################] 100%
 extra                                                                                             1965,9 KiB  2,21 MiB/s 00:01 [#############################################################################] 100%
 community                                                                                            5,8 MiB  2,96 MiB/s 00:02 [#############################################################################] 100%
 multilib                                                                                           194,8 KiB   885 KiB/s 00:00 [#############################################################################] 100%
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (1) npm-6.13.6-1

Total Installed Size:  20,63 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] y
(1/1) checking keys in keyring                                                                                                  [#############################################################################] 100%
(1/1) checking package integrity                                                                                                [#############################################################################] 100%
(1/1) loading package files                                                                                                     [#############################################################################] 100%
(1/1) checking for file conflicts                                                                                               [#############################################################################] 100%
error: failed to commit transaction (conflicting files)
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/LICENSE exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-access.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-adduser.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-audit.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-bin.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-bugs.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-build.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-bundle.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-cache.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-ci.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-completion.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-config.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-dedupe.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-deprecate.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-dist-tag.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-docs.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-doctor.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-edit.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-explore.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-fund.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-help-search.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-help.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-hook.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-init.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-install-ci-test.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-install-test.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-install.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-link.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-logout.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-ls.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-org.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-outdated.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-owner.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-pack.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-ping.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-prefix.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-profile.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-prune.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-publish.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-rebuild.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-repo.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-restart.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-root.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-run-script.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-search.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-shrinkwrap.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-star.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-stars.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-start.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-stop.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-team.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-test.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-token.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-uninstall.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-unpublish.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-update.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-version.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-view.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm-whoami.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/cli-commands/npm.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/configuring-npm/folders.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/configuring-npm/install.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/configuring-npm/npmrc.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/configuring-npm/package-json.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/configuring-npm/package-lock-json.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/configuring-npm/package-locks.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/configuring-npm/shrinkwrap-json.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/using-npm/config.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/using-npm/developers.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/using-npm/disputes.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/using-npm/orgs.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/using-npm/registry.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/using-npm/removal.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/using-npm/scope.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/using-npm/scripts.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/content/using-npm/semver.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/gatsby-browser.js exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/gatsby-config.js exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/gatsby-node.js exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/gatsby-ssr.js exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/package-lock.json exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/package.json exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-access/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-adduser/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-audit/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-bin/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-bugs/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-build/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-bundle/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-cache/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-ci/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-completion/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-config/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-dedupe/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-deprecate/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-dist-tag/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-docs/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-doctor/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-edit/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-explore/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-fund/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-help-search/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-help/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-hook/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-init/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-install-ci-test/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-install-test/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-install/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-link/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-logout/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-ls/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-org/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-outdated/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-owner/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-pack/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-ping/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-prefix/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-profile/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-prune/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-publish/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-rebuild/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-repo/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-restart/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-root/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-run-script/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-search/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-shrinkwrap/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-star/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-stars/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-start/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-stop/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-team/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-test/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-token/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-uninstall/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-unpublish/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-update/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-version/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-view/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm-whoami/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/cli-commands/npm/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/configuring-npm/folders/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/configuring-npm/install/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/configuring-npm/npmrc/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/configuring-npm/package-json/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/configuring-npm/package-lock-json/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/configuring-npm/package-locks/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/configuring-npm/shrinkwrap-json/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/google-fonts/s/inconsolata/v18/QldKNThLqRwH-OJ1UHjlKGlZ5q4.woff exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/google-fonts/s/inconsolata/v18/QldKNThLqRwH-OJ1UHjlKGlZ5qg.woff2 exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/google-fonts/s/inconsolata/v18/QldXNThLqRwH-OJ1UHjlKGHiw71p5_o.woff exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/google-fonts/s/inconsolata/v18/QldXNThLqRwH-OJ1UHjlKGHiw71p5_w.woff2 exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/google-fonts/s/poppins/v9/pxiByp8kv8JHgFVrLDz8Z1xlEw.woff exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/google-fonts/s/poppins/v9/pxiByp8kv8JHgFVrLDz8Z1xlFQ.woff2 exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/google-fonts/s/poppins/v9/pxiByp8kv8JHgFVrLGT9Z1xlEw.woff exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/google-fonts/s/poppins/v9/pxiByp8kv8JHgFVrLGT9Z1xlFQ.woff2 exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/google-fonts/s/poppins/v9/pxiEyp8kv8JHgFVrJJfecg.woff2 exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/google-fonts/s/poppins/v9/pxiEyp8kv8JHgFVrJJfedA.woff exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/icons/icon-144x144.png exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/icons/icon-192x192.png exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/icons/icon-256x256.png exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/icons/icon-384x384.png exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/icons/icon-48x48.png exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/icons/icon-512x512.png exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/icons/icon-72x72.png exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/icons/icon-96x96.png exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/static/d/2215187023.json exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/static/d/2417117884.json exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/static/network-icon-f659855f70bb0e12addd96250807c241.svg exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/styles.e93b5499b63484750fba.css exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/using-npm/config/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/using-npm/developers/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/using-npm/disputes/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/using-npm/orgs/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/using-npm/registry/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/using-npm/removal/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/using-npm/scope/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/using-npm/scripts/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/public/using-npm/semver/index.html exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/src/components/Accordion.js exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/src/components/Button.js exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/src/components/DocLinks.js exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/src/components/FoundTypo.js exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/src/components/MobileSidebar.js exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/src/components/Sidebar.js exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/src/components/home/DarkBlock.js exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/src/components/home/FeatureCard.js exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/src/components/home/Features.js exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/src/components/home/Footer.js exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/src/components/home/Terminal.js exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/src/components/home/Windows.js exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/src/components/home/cubes.js exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/src/components/home/hero.js exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/src/components/layout.js exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/src/components/links.js exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/src/components/navbar.js exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/src/components/scripts.js exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/src/components/seo.js exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/src/images/background-boxes.svg exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/src/images/background-cubes.svg exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/src/images/background-rectangles.svg exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/src/images/bracket.svg exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/src/images/cli-logo.svg exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/src/images/down-carrot.svg exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/src/images/hamburger-close.svg exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/src/images/hamburger.svg exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/src/images/manager-icon.svg exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/src/images/network-icon.svg exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/src/images/npm-icon.png exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/src/images/orange-cube.svg exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/src/images/pink-gradient-cube.svg exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/src/images/purple-cube.svg exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/src/images/purple-gradient-cube.svg exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/src/images/red-cube.svg exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/src/images/right-shadow-box.svg exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/src/images/terminal-icon.svg exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/src/images/test-icon.svg exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/src/images/up-carrot.svg exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/src/images/x.svg exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/src/main.css exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/src/pages/404.js exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/src/pages/index.js exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/src/templates/Page.js exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/src/theme.js exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/fund.js exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/fund.js exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/funding.js exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/man/man1/npm-fund.1 exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/man/man5/folders.5 exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/man/man5/install.5 exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/man/man5/package-json.5 exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/man/man5/package-lock-json.5 exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/man/man5/package-locks.5 exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/man/man5/shrinkwrap-json.5 exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/man/man7/config.7 exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/man/man7/developers.7 exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/man/man7/disputes.7 exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/man/man7/orgs.7 exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/man/man7/registry.7 exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/man/man7/removal.7 exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/man/man7/scope.7 exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/man/man7/scripts.7 exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/gentle-fs/lib/bin-link.js exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/https-proxy-agent/.editorconfig exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/https-proxy-agent/.eslintrc.js exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-normalize-package-bin/.github/settings.yml exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-normalize-package-bin/.npmignore exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-normalize-package-bin/LICENSE exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-normalize-package-bin/README.md exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-normalize-package-bin/index.js exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-normalize-package-bin/package-lock.json exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-normalize-package-bin/package.json exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-normalize-package-bin/test/array.js exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-normalize-package-bin/test/nobin.js exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-normalize-package-bin/test/object.js exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-normalize-package-bin/test/string.js exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/scripts/docs-build.js exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/share/man/man1/npm-fund.1 exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/share/man/man5/folders.5 exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/share/man/man5/install.5 exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/share/man/man5/package-json.5 exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/share/man/man5/package-lock-json.5 exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/share/man/man5/package-locks.5 exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/share/man/man5/shrinkwrap-json.5 exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/share/man/man7/config.7 exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/share/man/man7/developers.7 exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/share/man/man7/disputes.7 exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/share/man/man7/orgs.7 exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/share/man/man7/registry.7 exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/share/man/man7/removal.7 exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/share/man/man7/scope.7 exists in filesystem
npm: /usr/share/man/man7/scripts.7 exists in filesystem
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

What more can I do? I have even run "**sudo pacman -Rs npm**" and tried to reinstall and nothing done.

**EDITED**
Solved with commands

```
$ sudo pacman -Rns npm
$ sudo rm -R /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/
$ sudo rm -R /usr/share/man/man1/
$ sudo pacman -Syyu
$ sudo pacman -S npm
```

After, run :

```
$ sudo pacman -Syyu
$ sudo pacman -S npm
```

now I did this and got a clean system update!

Comment: `sudo rm /usr/share/man/man1/` man1 is a directory. `rm` doesn't work. Should I use `rm -rf` to remove the whole directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for asking this question and updating it with the right answer! I just wanted to add in a small change because there was a comment referencing it.

You forgot to add in the -R flag which recursively removes everything in the directory.

```
$ sudo pacman -Rns npm
$ sudo rm -R /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/
$ sudo rm -R /usr/share/man/man1/
$ sudo pacman -Syyu
$ sudo pacman -S npm
```

After, run :

```
$ sudo pacman -Syyu
$ sudo pacman -S npm
```

Hope this could help another passerby like me :)